# How to generate uuid string

Tags: python, uuid

Using `uuid` module I can generate an unique string (such as `c389fa3c-3a5c-4d8d-ac92-9b70f2bbe0b5`) using:

```
import uuid
result = uuid.uuid4()
print result
```

which results to:

```
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

Now, in order to get a generated string I would need to call `str()` function:

```
uuid_string = str(result)
print uuid_string
```

which prints:

```
c389fa3c-3a5c-4d8d-ac92-9b70f2bbe0b5
```

I wonder if there is a shorter way of generating the uuid text string as a string (without a need to use `str()` function).

Comment: "shorter" how? `str(...)` is only 5 characters

Comment: Funnily enough, UUID's documentation explicitly gives calling the `str()` function as the way to get a UUID string. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID)  Why don't you want to use the `str()` function, out of curiosity?

Comment: Anyway, when I'm doing `print(uuid.uuid4())` I'm getting the UUID itself (which makes perfect sense, since `print` invokes `__str__`). I'm using Python 3, so this may be a Python 2 vs 3 thing

Comment: `def u(): return str(uuid.uuid4())` and calling it with `u()` will be extremely short

Comment: @Sanyash and needlessly "convoluted".

Comment: Write your own uuid generator

Comment: @mad_ How will reinventing the wheel help solve a problem that doesn't really exist?

Comment: @DeepSpace That will at least give a sense of satisfaction

Comment: my mistake - thought you were the initial questioner. Will remove :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `.hex` attribute to get the string value without `-`

```
In [1]: import uuid

In [2]: result = uuid.uuid4()

In [3]: result.hex
Out[3]: '536bc225eb6d47589b1858f265b809b1'

In [4]: print(result.hex)
536bc225eb6d47589b1858f265b809b1
```

Here is the related documentation:

```
UUIDs have these read-only attributes:

bytes       the UUID as a 16-byte string (containing the six
            integer fields in big-endian byte order)

bytes_le    the UUID as a 16-byte string (with time_low, time_mid,
            and time_hi_version in little-endian byte order)

fields      a tuple of the six integer fields of the UUID,
            which are also available as six individual attributes
            and two derived attributes:

        time_low                the first 32 bits of the UUID
        time_mid                the next 16 bits of the UUID
        time_hi_version         the next 16 bits of the UUID
        clock_seq_hi_variant    the next 8 bits of the UUID
        clock_seq_low           the next 8 bits of the UUID
        node                    the last 48 bits of the UUID

        time                    the 60-bit timestamp
        clock_seq               the 14-bit sequence number

hex         the UUID as a 32-character hexadecimal string

int         the UUID as a 128-bit integer

urn         the UUID as a URN as specified in RFC 4122

variant     the UUID variant (one of the constants RESERVED_NCS,
            RFC_4122, RESERVED_MICROSOFT, or RESERVED_FUTURE)

version     the UUID version number (1 through 5, meaningful only
            when the variant is RFC_4122)
```

Comment: Actually, it's not about saving one character. It's more about using the given functionality without calling an unnecessary method.

Comment: when to use `str(uuid.uuid4())` and when `uuid.uuid4().hex` ?